# Local limitations of function usage

Tags: c

What's the reason for FOO returning '0' in the final answer:

```
 int FOO = 0, bar = 0, i;
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     int FOO = i;
     printf("%d ", FOO);
     if (i % 2 == 0)
         FOO += bar;
     bar++;
 }
 printf("%d %d", FOO, bar);
```

Comment: You create two variables, both called `FOO`. That's not a particularly good idea.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the foo loop, you defined a variable with the same name `FOO`, this will shadow the `FOO` in the outside, which means, the `FOO` you use in the loop is a variable local to the block only. The final `printf` is outside the loop, so the `FOO` it prints is the one resides in the outside scope. The shadowed `FOO` no longer exists at the this point.
So the code can be treat as same as this:

```
int FOO_out = 0, bar = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int FOO_in = i;
    printf("%d ", FOO_in);
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        FOO_in += bar;
    bar++;
}
printf("%d %d", FOO_out, bar);
```